# SSL certificates and DNS CNAME

Tags: domain-name-system, ssl, certificate, cname-record, alias

I am wondering if an SSL certificate would work and be accepted in the following circumstances.  In each of these circumstances, one DNS name returns a CNAME record for another DNS name, and the client is connecting to the server based on the alias name:

1) The DNS name `www.example.com` returns a CNAME record for `www.example2.com`.  The server at the IP address for `www.example2.com` is running a web server.  A web browser connects to the site using the name `https://www.example.com` (resolving to the CNAME `www.example2.com` and subsequently to the IP address).  The SSL certificate returned by the server is for only `www.example2.com`.  Will/should the browser consider the certificate to be valid for this connection?  Is this implementation-defined based on the browser that is being used, or is the behavior defined by a standard?

2) The DNS name `mx.example.com` returns a CNAME record for `mx.example2.com`.  The server at the IP address for `mx.example2.com` is running a SMTP server with SSL support.  A SMTP client (e.g. a mail transfer agent) connects to the server using the name `mx.example.com` (which it resolves to the CNAME `mx.example2.com` and subsequently to the IP address).  The SSL certificate returned by the server is only for `mx.example2.com`.  Will/should the client consider the certificate to be valid for this connection?  Is this implementation-defined based on the client being used, or is this behavior defined by a standard?

3) The DNS name `imap.example.com` returns a CNAME record for `imap.example2.com`.  The server at the IP address for `imap.example2.com` is running a IMAP server with SSL support.  A mail application connects to the server using the name `imap.example.com` (which it resolves to the CNAME `imap.example2.com` and subsequently to the IP address).  The SSL certificate returned by the server is only for `imap.example2.com`.  Will/should the mail application consider the certificate to be valid for this connection?  Is this implementation-defined based on the application being used, or is this behavior defined by a standard?

Answer (score 3):

The only thing which matters for certificate validation is the domain name used to connect. Since this name does not change on DNS CNAME you get:

> The DNS name www.example.com ... web server ... certificate returned by the server is for only www.example2.com

The browser will fail but might give you an option to override this decision.

> The DNS name mx.example.com  ... SMTP ... certificate returned by the server is only for mx.example2.com

Mail clients which properly check the certificate will fail but many mail clients have an option to ignore certificate failures. Most mail servers do not properly check the certificate and will accept anything.

> The DNS name imap.example.com ... IMAP ..  A mail application connects to the server using the name imap.example.com

Same as with SMTP, i.e. they will fail if they properly check the certificate but many have an option to ignore certificate errors.